# What is the video-conferencing limit of Microsoft Lync

Tags: lync, video-conferencing

How many people can participate in a video-conferencing call using Microsoft Lync?

--

By contrast, Skype supports up to 10 people using video-conferencing.  Once that number is exceeded video-conferencing is disabled entirely, but then 25 people can participate in an audio-only conference.  How does Microsoft Lync work?

Answer (score 2):

[Answered by @ryanlowdermilk from Twitter:](https://twitter.com/#!/ryanlowdermilk/status/169526564403417088)

> @gabesumner no hard limit, 250 multi-party video. however, not
>   "hollywood squares" style; it would be speaker highlighted style.

This also supports a discussion I was seeing in the [Microsoft TechNet forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/ocscapacityplanning/thread/576ad266-2981-4bb2-b1fa-6d40d1eac1d5).

Comment: Wrote a blog post on this topic - http://gabesumner.com/wanted-video-conferencing-solutions-for-mid-sized-teams - I'm not looking to self promote, simply trying to provide a public record of my exploration of this topic.